# Template error while templating string: unexpected char u - Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

When executing a playbook to run a command in a remote host and pass the output using shell, getting below error.

> fatal: [master1]: FAILED! => {} MSG: template error while templating
>   string: unexpected char u'a' at 4. String:
>   {{54aa7fda16833bff8358b6bd1157df2d9caa26b2}}

Below is my playbook content

```
- name: 'Play1' 

  hosts: master 

  tasks: 

   - name: 'Execute command' 

     shell: ''sh generate_ticket.sh" #command to generate ticket 

     register: shell_output 

   - name: 'debug shell_output' 

     debug: 

      var="{{ shell_output.stdout | from_yaml }}"
```

When I try the same with msg and don't try to filter then the output is printed without any error. However I prefer to use var as it suits best for my further requirements. If the ticket number is a different string I do not face any issues. Please see below:

Output:

```
ok: [master1] => {}


MSG:


54aa7fda16833bff8358b6bd1157df2d9caa26b2


Playbook :

- name: 'Play1' 

  hosts: master 

  tasks: 

   - name: 'Execute command' 

     shell: ''sh generate_ticket.sh" #command to generate ticket 

     register: shell_output 

   - name: 'debug shell_output' 

     debug: msg="{{ shell_output.stdout | from_yaml }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `!unsafe`

[enter link description here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work when I put single quotes around `shell_output.stdout`

`var="{{ 'shell_output.stdout' | from_yaml}}"`

Let me know if anybody has a better fix than this.