# Problems trying to extract username and password from configuration file using a regular expression pattern

Tags: regex, ansible, regex-group

I would need to extract an username and a password from a configuration file.

```
define( 'DB_USER', 'username' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );
```

So far I managed to extract a string, using this code:

```
- set_fact:
    dbuser: "{{ wpconfig.stdout | regex_search('DB_USER(.+)', '\\1') | first }}"
```

Output

```
ok: [prod_server] => {
    "dbuser": "', 'username' );"
}
```

I would need to extract only the `username` part and get rid of all other characters.

I tried to play a bit with regular expressions, and I managed to build up one that apparently extracts the `username` part putting it into Group 1: https://regex101.com/r/OzJR1X/2

If I try to add it to my code, an error shows up:

```
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unknown escape character 's'
```

Comment: Did you try double escaping the `\\s` like `'DB_USER',\\s'(.*?)'`

Comment: Hi,
Yes, already did that... it throws an error: ```An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv```

Comment: What is the error from the traceback?

Comment: This is the traceback: ```jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '\\' at 44```

Comment: Did you try adding single quotes as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60336719/template-error-while-templating-string-unexpected-char-u-ansible)?

Comment: You mean to put ```wpconfig.stdout``` between single quotes? like this ```'wpconfig.stdout'```?
Tried and the same error shows up... ```unexpected char '\\' at 44```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary of the parameters. Given the list of the lines, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        wpconfig_list: "{{ lookup('file', 'wpconfig.conf').splitlines() }}"
```

```yaml
  wpconfig_list:
  - define( 'DB_USER', 'username' );
  - define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );
```

---

**Fit the code to your needs potentially using `wpconfig.stdout_lines`**

---

The task creates the dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        wpconfig_dict: "{{ wpconfig_dict|default({})|
                           combine({_key: _val}) }}"
      loop: "{{ wpconfig_list }}"
      vars:
        _regex1: '^.*\((.*),(.*)\).*$'
        _regex2: "'"
        _key: "{{ item|regex_replace(_regex1, '\\1')|trim|
                       regex_replace(_regex2, '') }}" 
        _val: "{{ item|regex_replace(_regex1, '\\2')|trim|
                       regex_replace(_regex2, '') }}"
```

```yaml
  wpconfig_dict:
    DB_PASSWORD: password
    DB_USER: username
```

Select the user, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dbuser: "{{ wpconfig_dict.DB_USER }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  dbuser: username
```